# Can you add a language without forcing a rebuild?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017

My app has been designed to be able to run on two different languages, english and czech. In order to accomplish this, I've created 2 resource files:

[image]

If an end-user would like to add another language, for example `GlobalStrings.fr-FR.resx`, **is it possible to allow for this functionality without rebuilding the application?**

If we look at the properties of these resource files:

[image]

I'm not understanding what *embedded resource* means. Does this mean that in order for the app to consume this file, *the application must be rebuilt?*

**How do we create a resource file, that is open to be extended/changed by the end user, without having to rebuild the entire application
?**

Comment: yep, it's possible. Read more about resources here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/globalizing-and-localizing-applications and use this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager

Comment: yes, using that plug in is awesome!! still not understanding though how to allow the client to edit values

Comment: not sure why alex deleted his post, but it was VERY good, unfortunately, mid-way it disappeared

Comment: I restored it... While checking if everything is right I found article about plain text version of resources and though if we actually support plain text in addition to compiled assembly (thus invalidating the answer), but it turned out to be just another way to specify source for compiled resource assembly - link in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Regular .Net resources are compiled into assembly with particular name and loaded by matching that name. So if "end-user" is ok to translate strings in resx file and compile resources into assembly with particular name (like "MyResources.cs-cz.dll") you can do that with default .Net behavior without recompiling main code. See [MSDN:Packing and Deploying resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/packaging-and-deploying-resources-in-desktop-apps) and related links for more information.

Note that you don't need Visual Studio for it and can use csc command line compiler to [embed resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/resource-compiler-option) on user's machine - so if your really want you can provide simple script that compiles corresponding resx locally. Note that editing XML (resx) as text is generally not possible by regular person due to required encoding of some characters - consider technical level of your "end-users" before going that route. [Plain text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps#TextFiles) version of source for resource may work in more cases.

Usually this is not the case - if end-user localization is requirement you would create some sort of custom resource string management by loading strings from plain text files or database that users can update locally.